# How to set stack (non initial) commit size of main thread

Tags: delphi, winapi, stack, delphi-7, delphi-xe

The question is not about the minimal stack size (initial commited size). 
I found how to do it in VS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx.

In delphi 7(In XE possible to make it easier),  I can offer after сompiling edit PE header manually by own utility. But it may have a solution easier.

Comment: There's no such thing as setting non initial commit size. Memory is committed as required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$MINSTACKSIZE` and `$MAXSTACKSIZE` directives to control what gets written to the PE file. The directives control the stack commit and reserve sizes respectively. As an alternative to using two separate directives you can control both values at once with the `$M` directive. The documentation is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Memory_allocation_sizes_(Delphi)

These settings can also be controlled in the project options. The location of these options vary between IDE versions but they are found with the linker options: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Linking

Comment: I don't see any option to set the commit size?!

Comment: @Lieven the commit size is `$MINSTACKSIZE`. The reserve size is `$MAXSTACKSIZE`.

Comment: To get me on the right track: the default commit size for VS is 4KB then and the default commit size for Delphi is 16KB?

Comment: To test I use VMMap utility. Threads of different applications (x32) have blocks with flag Page_Guard with different sizes 4k, 8k, 12k, 16k. As a rule PG blocks of stack Delphi 7 app's have a size 4k, Delphi XE - 8k. I need to set the 16k. Parameters stack min / max size it does not affect

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. These settings do what I say. They control the stack commit and reserve size values written to the PE file. Exactly the same as do `/STACK` in the MS tool chain.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken. I assumed that Page_Guard is setted to all of the pages included in the every new commit. But if it is not, then I do not understand why the size of the blocks with the flag of Page_Guard is not constant for different threads.

Comment: There are two settings in the PE file relating to stacks. The commit and reserve size. Those are what /STACK controls in the MS tools. And those are what the Delphi directives that I referred to control. I understood your question to be that you wanted to know the Delphi equivalent to /STACK. Did I get that wrong?

Comment: It seems that there is no. 
There was confusion in words. In the MSDN says about SizeOfStackCommit, and about Delphi minimal size of the stack. I expect that these are different parameters. I'm looking for an opportunity to adjust the size of each commit with an increase in the stack.

Comment: They are the same parameters. That's what my answer says. They are all you've got to work with. There's nothing else. I guess if these Delphi options don't solve your problem, whatever it is, `/STACK` is no use to you either.

Comment: @cemick - But that's what the `$MINSTACKSIZE` does?!

Comment: @Lieven set only initial virtual memory commited size. Or misunderstanding of how many pages have assigned Page_Guard after commit on increase of stack size.

Comment: @cemick - afaik, setting page guard pages is not controlled by the VS setting either. Adding page guard pages is done while requesting memory or by using gflags?!

Comment: Anyway, I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers
VMMap screenshots:
My app http://1drv.ms/1rxN2Fm
TotalCommander32  http://1drv.ms/1rxNjId

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers 
Just noticed that TotalCommander chose recording x64 thread. Fail.

Comment: I agree with David, you seem to be asking a completely different question here. *(btw, the screenshots are blocked for me)*. VMMap shows the protection settings of the memory block. It doesn't show the commit size *(Committed is not the commit size described in your article)*